# Vuejs counter condition not working when value is reset

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to implement a datepicker where you flick through the months.
The objective is to reset the month counter when it reaches -1 or 11.
Counting up, it works just fine, but counting down it does not reset the value once it reaches -1 and I don't understand why.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="count(1)">Count up</button>
    <button @click="count(-1)">Count down</button>
    <button @click="reset">reset</button>
    <div>Value: {{ value }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
methods: {
    reset(){ this.value = 5 },
    count(num) {
      var x = this.value + num;
      console.log(x)

      if (x < 0) { 
        this.value = 11; 
      }
      if (x > 11) {
        this.value = 0;
      } else {
        this.value = x;
      }
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: 5,
    };
  },
```

Here's the [code sandbox](https://9grt1.csb.app/)

Comment: Because you didn't use `else if (x > 11)`. For `x === 0` you set `this.value = 11;` then immediately (because `x <= 11`) `this.value = x;` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to

```js
if (x < 0) {
  this.value = 11;
} else if (x > 11) {
  this.value = 0;
} else {
  this.value = x;
}
```

And it will work :)

The reason is that for now when the value is less than 0 it enters the first condition (`if (x < 0)`) and then it still enters the `else` so `this.value` is set to `x`.

Comment: OK thanks @BTL, the penny has dropped. without the else if, the else condition only applies to the second if statement, right ? DOH

Comment: Yes, that's it!